# Excel formula into C# implementation

Tags: c#, excel, formula

So my goal is to implement an Excel formula in C#, but I am unable to produce exact results.

The Excel formula:

```
=(V11-AH11)*(-1+(1+M12)^((I12-J12)/365)) where  

V11 = 500000  
AH11 = 10000  
M12 = 0.41%  
I12 = 3/1/2016 (mm/dd/yyyy)  
J12 = 2/1/2016 (mm/dd/yyyy)
```

Result = `159.96`

my C# implementation:

```
result = Convert.ToDouble((V11 - AH11) * (-1 + Math.Pow((1 + M12), (((Convert.ToDateTime(I12) - Convert.ToDateTime(J12)).TotalDays / 365)))));
```

Result : `159.32`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, for starters, when I plugged your numbers into Excel, it too reported 159.3187, you sure you're checking the right thing? For instance, if any of these numbers are calculated, they might have more accuracy than being displayed (I'm looking at you, `0.41%`)

Comment: @Roma or `365d`

Comment: @RomaDoskoch, `.TotalDays` is already a `double`, so that won't change anything.

Comment: When I copy past this into C# then I get a result of "461.47457991864371"!

Comment: @RomaDoskoch tried that. Same result :(

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Check your DateTime values perhaps? I got 159.31875 in both Excel and C# (+/- some extra fractional digits).

Comment: I'm telling you, the problem isn't with the C# code, the problem is with your assumptions. For some reason the numbers doesn't line up with your expected result. If anything, I'd say the C# code is the correct one as manually checking this via a calculator also tells me the same value. Your Excel spreadsheet is either faulty, or you have more accuracy in some of these numbers than you see on screen. If the percentage is calculated and is really more like 0,41165%, you just **see** 0,41% on screen, then you get a result more similar to what you wanted.

Comment: See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(500000-10000)*(-1%2B(1%2B0.41%2F100)%5E(29%2F365))) and click the "More digits" button over the result that shows `159.319..`

Comment: Here I asked [Wolfram Alpha to solve for the percentage to get 159.96](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(500000-10000)*(-1%2B(1%2BX%2F100)%5E(29%2F365))%3D159.96) and it reported back that the percentage must be `0.411653`. This of course assuming that it is the percentage that has a higher accuracy. In reality any of the numbers in the spreadsheet may have this problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 0.41% comes from Excel's XIRR function, but when used in the aforementioned formula it comes as a hard-coded value from cell M12.
If I understand correctly, that is what you meant to ask, right?
My apologies if I have misinterpreted.

Comment: Well, then your Excel is broken, if none of the numbers have more accuracy than you've posted here then you've found a bug in Excel because the formula as posted should not give that result, it should give the result you got from C#.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I wouldn't jump to that conclusion yet :P I am going to recheck my values and be right back :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you my friend are a life savior. It was indeed a problem of incorrect values. I was truncating 0.411653 to 0.41 in my C# code for display purposes and hence the incorrect result. Thank you very much. And also, thank you for introducing me to wolframalpha. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here must be with accuracy.

Even [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(500000-10000)*(-1%2B(1%2B0.41%2F100)%5E(29%2F365)) agrees with C#, the result is closer to 159.32 than it is to 159.96.

My bet would be the percentage, which looks calculated, all the other numbers are nice whole integer like numbers.

I asked Wolfram Alpha to solve for the percentage in order to get the result 159.96 and it came back with [0.411653](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(500000-10000)*(-1%2B(1%2BX%2F100)%5E(29%2F365))%3D159.96)

So the C# code is the most correct, your Excel assumptions are at fault, you have more accuracy than you're displaying.

Comment: Was exactly the case. Thank you :)